# QGIS program to search qgs / qgz with specific data source layer

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I need to search for all layers pointing to a specific datasource across all the project files (.qgs / .qgz) in a directory or drive.

It's necessary in a myriad of situations, e.g. when deciding to either directly edit or copy and then edit a datasource, I usually need to check and make sure the edit is not rendering related layers useless or buggy; if so, I'd need to edit a copy of the datasource instead.

Another situation is when I know I have an already set up layer and need to reuse it but can't remember exactly which of the several hundred projects has it, and narrowing down the search to the ones using that particular datasource would come very handy.

I already have a script that does this for .mxd files. I just don't know enough Python for QGIS to be able to tell if it's possible. Nevertheless, it absolutely should be, I see no reason to think otherwise.

Solutions in any other programming language would be welcome as well (provided it's a language with tutorials online, please).

Comment: Thank you for the prompt reply and suggestion. Please, would you happen to know about some tutorial to "walk" a drive's or directory's xml files and check what's inside them?

Comment: Gotta say I'm not really that familiar with the code in the example you kindly provided. Wouldn't want to bug it because I wouldn't have the time to debug it...

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to use PyQGIS.

`.qgs` files are just text (XML) files and `.qgz` are zip files with a `.qgs` inside.  So what you need to do is `os.walk` a directory, look for `.qgz` files, unzip them (in memory) and parse the XML .qgs file to extract the data sources:

```
from fnmatch import filter
from os import (walk, path)
from xml.etree import ElementTree
from zipfile import ZipFile


def find_qgzs(in_dir):
    for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in walk(in_dir):
        for qgz in filter(filenames, '*.qgz'):
            qgz_path = path.join(dirpath, qgz)
            yield qgz_path


def get_data_sources(qgz_path):
    data_sources = set()
    with ZipFile(qgz_path, 'r') as in_qgz:
        for f in in_qgz.infolist():
            if f.filename.endswith('.qgs'):
                tree = ElementTree.XML(in_qgz.read(f.filename))  # .decode('UTF-8')
                # {} is a set comprehension to filter dupes
                data_sources |= {e.text for e in tree.findall("./projectlayers/maplayer/datasource")}
    return list(data_sources)


def main(in_dir):

    for qgz_path in find_qgzs(in_dir):
        qgz_sources = get_data_sources(qgz_path)

        # Do something with qgz_sources... here I just print them
        print('{} data sources:'.format(qgz_path))
        print('\t'+'\n\t'.join(qgz_sources))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    in_dir = r'path/to/look/for/qgzs'
    main(in_dir)
```